# Manga/Webtoon where a woman transports to a demon's realm in her sleep

Tags: story-identification, manga, webcomics

A woman goes to sleep and in her “dream” she is in a demon/devil's room and sleeps with him. She wakes up and is back in her bed and thinks it’s just a dream.

She keeps transporting to his realm when she sleeps thinking it’s just a continuous dream. She’s powerful in his realm and is able to break his magic spells. He tries to keep her there but every time she wakes up she disappears from his realm.

Her switching realms has something to do with the painting in her room I think?? She has a nosy friend that she tells the dreams to her about.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

Comment: Is this a sexually explicit work, or is the "sleeps with him" part mostly subtext? Do you remember what either character looked like? In particular, did the demon have any non-human characteristics (horns, different skin color, jewels embedded in his skin, stuff like that), or is he just a demon because he's involved in these dreams? Did he look like someone she knew, e.g. her boss?

Comment: Yes sexually. Unsure of where I read it could have been on WEBTOON or a similar site. He was either a devil or a demon. He had horns I think. Not exactly sure what he looked like.

Comment: @Ashlyn Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You seem to have created a second account; please see the help on [merging accounts](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) so you can edit additional details directly into the question.

Comment: Was this full color or black and white? Was this a oneshot, or a series with multiple chapters? Do you remember about how many chapters there were when you read it? Does the demon ever appear in the real world, or only inside the dreams?

Comment: It was in full color and he only appeared in dreams. There was maybe around 10? She thought her dreams were just dreams but they were real and she was transporting to his world.

Comment: Ive been looking for this same story! The demon king has long white/silver hair I think he has a jewel on his forehead. He is helping her learn her magik and in her reality she's also getting help from her boss. Who looks Nothing like the demon king. She starts off as a janitor but gets a better paying job thanks to him.

Answer (score 1):

Blood Reverie on [WEBTOON](https://www.webtoons.com/en/romance/blood-reverie/list?title_no=2806):

> Cassia works a Dead-End job, lives in a cramped apartment, and can't remember her own last name. Good thing she has a sexy vampire boyfriend who lives in her dreams- if only he were real, then maybe life wouldn't suck so bad.

I'm hoping there is a book like it though

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you describe how *Blood Reverie* matches the question?  It's best if you match each point in the question, like a painting in her room, with a specific detail from the webcomic.