# Manhwa where woman travels to another world with historical setting in her sleep

Tags: story-identification, manga

The female lead (FL) basically meets this CEO of a company (introduced by her Professor) for some collaboration (cosmetics I think). The woman has red hair.

However, the FL when sleeping at night enters another world which looks ancient and in the body of a maid that looks just like her. The maid (FL) is thrown into the bedchambers of her Lord as a substitute to his fiancee to spend a night with him. This is because the Lord basically is afflicted by a condition which can turn him into a savage and ultimately kill people. Only his mate (I think) can calm that condition. So his fiancee throws this FL in her place to deal with him as a sacrifice in the case the fiancee is not his true mate. Lo and Behold, instead of any killing the historical FL with the modern soul manages to calm down the Lord/ML and it becomes a night of passion.
And then it is revealed that the Lord has the same face as the CEO. The Lord has long white hair (I think... or could it be black??).

Basically the two worlds exist independently but the FL in her sleep can cross over and enter the body of the historical version of her. Even the people around FL in the modern world exist in the historical world as they to start getting pulled into that realm. The ML and FL fall in love first in the historical world which transfers to the modern world but neither of them know that they both are the same people in historical setting in their sleep.

Plus the antagonists in the modern world also exist in the historical world even maybe having different genders.

Finally, an extra information is that the best friend of the FL travels to historical world but into a cat. And because the soul within is human, people think the cat is holy due to its abilities to maybe read and understand humans.

Comment: Similar premise to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/267840 but I don't believe this is *Blood Reverie*.

Answer (score 2):

This is *[Survival Marriage](https://anilist.co/manga/127434/Saengjongyeolhon/)*.

> Next to impossible coincidences seem to be connected to a **shared dream**… Is this destiny?
>
> Chayee springs out of bed after one of the most realistic and steamy dreams she’s ever had. After bringing herself back to reality, she goes to work as a T.A. at her former university. But, while on an errand for her professor, she meets Dohun and gets the shock of her life. He… seriously resembles the man she spent a hot night in the dream. She finds herself unable to face him since every glance brings back the very realistic feelings of the night before!
>
> “By any chance, have we… met before?”
>
> Dohun also has unexplainable feelings of discomfort towards Chayee and puts as much space between them as he can. But, no matter how hard they try, fate keeps dragging them back towards each other. What’s going on?! **When dreams and reality intertwine**, anything can happen!

[image: Cover image]

The cover image shows the modern-day characters; FL has orange-ish or red hair, ML has black hair.

The story opens in the fantasy world, where the FL is in the bridal chamber of a half-human who is in the middle of transforming into a beast and comes close to killing her. She manages to calm him down and they embrace, and she wakes up as her modern day self, thinking it's merely an extremely realistic dream.

She discusses this with her friend/roommate; it is mentioned that she was merely a maid and not supposed to be in the chamber.

[image: FL is a maid in the dream world]

When the FL goes into work as a TA at her university she by chance runs into a man who is the spitting image of the lord from her dream. He is revealed to be the CEO of a cosmetics company.

I did not read enough to confirm the parts about other people being pulled into the other world, or the bit about the cat, but everything else is a perfect match.